# Replacing URLs in Strings - Perl

Tags: perl, url

I have a bunch of strings that have URLs in them and I need to remove the URL and replace it with a different one. The only way I can think of to do it is with `split`:

```
($start, $url, $end) = split(/:/);
```

But I don't think this is the right way to go about it, because if the url is at the start or end of the string it won't work properly.

Any ideas greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you supply a couple of examples of what you want to do with the strings?

Answer (score 6):

Try using [URI::Find](http://p3rl.org/URI%3a%3aFind).

Answer (score 2):

The already-suggested [URI::Find](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI-Find) looks to be a good bet.

Alternatively, [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common) can provide suitable URLs to match URLs, for instance:

```
use Regexp::Common qw(URI);
my $string = "Some text, http://www.google.com/search?q=foo and http://www.twitter.com/";
$string =~ s{$RE{URI}}{http://stackoverflow.com/}g;
```

The above would replace both the URLs with `http://stackoverflow.com/` as an example.

Answer (score 1):

[URI::URL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI/Split.pm) is your friend.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use URI::Split qw(uri_split uri_join);
my ($scheme, $auth, $path, $query, $frag) = uri_split($uri);
my $uri = uri_join($scheme, $auth, $path, $query, $frag);
```

Comment: URI::Split is for splitting a URL into its component parts, not for finding URLs in a string that also contains other text.

Comment: The OP is not trying to find URLs inside other text. It is stated in the original question that there is "a bunch of strings with URLs in them" and nothing else. Even the example given is using 'split'. Now, I do agree that the problem is actually two problems.

Answer (score 0):

if you also have multiple input files, and need to consistently change strings in all input files, this script can come in handy:

http://unixgods.org/~tilo/replace_string/